# Android JSON null pointer exception error and android.view.WindowLeaked

Tags: php, android, json, nullpointerexception

I am a novice in developing an android application,but here its is. I am trying to design an application to get the users GPS location, so I have got the code to get the GPS location, as well as the .php page to post the data,but the problem I am facing is that,but now I am stuck with a null pointer exception error and android.view.WindowLeaked.

```
package com.wise.ezzie_taxie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

double latitude;
double longitude;
String IMEINumber;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

// url to add coordinates
private static final String url_add_coordinate = "http://10.0.2.2/project/create.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
private static final String TAG_IMEI = "imeino";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLoation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            IMEINumber = tm.getDeviceId();// get IMEI no.

            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude
                        + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

            new Entercoordinate().execute();
        }

    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class Entercoordinate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("adding new coordinate..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * adding new coordinate
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String lati = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String longi = String.valueOf(longitude);
        String imeino = String.valueOf(IMEINumber);

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LATITUDE, lati));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LONGITUDE, longi));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_IMEI, imeino));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add_coordinate,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat for response
        // Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully entered coordinate
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your Location is added successfully ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to enter coordinate
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your Location is not added successfully ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

my gps tracker class is
    package com.wise.ezzie_taxie;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

/*
 * COMMENTS LocationListner is used for receiving notifications from the
 * LocationManager when the location has changed.
 * refrence:http://developer.android.
 * .com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html to access system
 * services global variable declaration to use anywhere
 */

private final Context mContext;


// GPS status flag to check if GPS is switched on or not
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// network status flag to check if network provider connection is switched
// on or not
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            alertDialog.setMessage("no network provider is enabled");
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

// Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
// app

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

// Function to get latitude

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

// Function to get longitude

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
 * launch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button, to display settings pages
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    // on pressing cancel button, to cancel
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

my json parser class is

```
package com.wise.ezzie_taxie;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

             httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);// Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
             httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();// Extract data from the response.
             //is =  httpEntity.getContent();// Open an inputStream with the data content.

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(httpEntity !=null)
            {
                Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
            }
            else{
                Log.i("NULL", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
            }

        }
        if(httpEntity != null)
        {
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            //Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
        } else {
             httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
             is = httpEntity.getContent();
            //Log.i("NULL", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "ISO-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);// Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        String line = null;// Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        line = reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {// Build the string until null.
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();// Close the input stream.
        json = sb.toString();// Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        //json = json.replaceAll("db_connect.php", "");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

my php code to post looks like dis

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && isset($_POST['imeino'])) {    
$lat = $_POST['latitude'];
$long = $_POST['longitude'];
$imei = $_POST['imeino'];

// include db connect class
require_once '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO coordinate(imei, latitude, longitude) VALUES('$imei','$lat', '$long')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "entry successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

my logcat shows me the following error..

```
10-18 02:52:55.920: D/GPS Enabled(427): GPS Enabled
10-18 02:52:58.550: E/JSON Parser(427): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-18 02:52:58.550: W/dalvikvm(427): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-18 02:52:58.710: D/dalvikvm(427): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2568 objects / 165384 bytes in 144ms
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.wise.ezzie_taxie.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$Entercoordinate.doInBackground(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:137)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.wise.ezzie_taxie.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$Entercoordinate.doInBackground(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:1)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-18 02:52:58.710: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  ... 4 more
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427): Activity com.wise.ezzie_taxie.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45fcf4c0 that was originally added here
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.wise.ezzie_taxie.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45fcf4c0 that was originally added here
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.wise.ezzie_taxie.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$Entercoordinate.onPreExecute(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:109)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.wise.ezzie_taxie.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:87)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-18 02:52:59.350: E/WindowManager(427):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

guys desperate help needed.

Comment: Can we have a better view for `AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java line 137`

Comment: AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java line 137:-  `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`     although the entry is shown in the database, the application crashes.

Comment: I think your first problem is the `JSONException` as there are some invalid character at index 0 and the second problem is `TAG_SUCCESS` is null because the first one encountered the problem. Could you post your `JSON` as well ?

Comment: `{
    "success": 0,
    "message": "Required field(s) is missing"
}` and like for others